# Repeating Commands in C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, command-line

To test my program, I have to manually input many line of commands which are in order. Say after running the console application of main.exe, I type many commands, command1, command2, command3.....command50. Each commands closely depends on previous command. It's tremendously annoying that I have to start fresh if an error occurs in middle. For instance, I encounter an error w/command30. I must restart the program and repeat very single command. I just wonder how can I write some codes embedding into the main.exe and behaving like unix arrow key to repeat previous commands? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have many commands you need to run in sequence I'd put them in a text file and have the program read and execute that.

Comment: That's a broad question, so here's a broad answer: State machines.

Answer (score 2):

> I just wonder how can I write some codes embedding into the main.exe and behaving like unix arrow key to repeat previous commands?

You can use stack, everytime you enter a command you push it to stack, when user press up arrow key, start iterating over the stack one by one, when user press enter key, take the command from stack and execute it( also push it onto stack).

Comment: With the error appearing, the program must be  terminated and restarted. Does the stack still keep the commands typed?

Comment: no stack will not keep the commands in memory, you can save the commands to some file and when restarting the program load the commands from the file using file stream